# Can I disable (via configuration) export to PDF in Jupyter Hub?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

The subject pretty much says it all. In Jupyter Hub (and also the previous notebook server), there is an option under the file menu to export to PDF. If you don't have xetex or similar installed, it will break. I would like to disable this menu entry in a standard way (i.e., not by forking the codebase!).

Can I do this? If so, how? If not, how hard would it be to implement a patch for this?